# Repeat values in a column based on another

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have an array (not necessarily square)

```
my_array = ['name_1', 3
            'name_2', 2]
```

and I want to end up with an list (or numpy array etc) of `length 3+2=5` where the first three positions are assigned to `'name_1'` and the next 2 to `'name_2'`. Hence the output will be

```
['name_1', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_2']
```

This is what I have done so far; Is there a better way to do this please?

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([['name_1', 3], ['name_2', 2]])
l = []
for i in range(my_array.shape[0]):
    x = [my_array[i, 0].tolist()] * np.int(my_array[i, 1])
    l.append(x)

flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)
```

which prints:

```
['name_1', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_2']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat`:

```
my_array[:,0].repeat(my_array[:,1].astype(int))
# array(['name_1', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_2'], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input, several different approaches here, all very helpful. Didn't expect so many different ways really. Unfortunately I haven't run a "horse race" to compare execution times, but I am accepting coldspeed's answer because it is succinct, compact, easy to understand and also new to me; hadn't seen np.repeat until now. Special shout-out to Travis for the extensive explanation but also for his extra time to come up with two solutions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of list multiplication and `sum`:

```
sum(([my_array[i]] * my_array[i+1] for i in range(0, len(my_array), 2)), [])
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` to concatenate lists this way. Use `itertools.chain`, but even then this is still quite excessive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a numpy expert, and "better" way is subjective. Here's one way using `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
chain.from_iterable(repeat(elem, count) for elem, count in zip(my_array[::2], my_array[1::2]))
```

Here's a breakdown of how it works.

`my_array[::2]` returns a slice that is every other element, since the first and and second arguments are left empty, it starts at 0 and goes to the end. So that will be all of your first column, which are your input elements. Your counts are in the other column, so we can use `my_array[1::2]` to get the counts. These slices are nice, because they don't create new copies of your array, just "views" that skip every other element and start at some offset.

Now we want to enumerate those in pairs. Using `zip()` is handy for that. It consumes iterators/generators/sequences in parallel and gives an individual binding for each element. So as we zip through in the for construct, we bind each element to `elem`, and each count to `count`.

The `for in` construct allows us to provide a transform for each pair of arguments. Here we use `repeat` to build up virtual repetitions of each element. A nice thing again, is that we don't actually have to create new arrays. The `repeat` generator will just produce the input element N times.

Finally, we want a way to string all of this repeated elements into one flattened enumeration. That's where `chain.from_iterable()` comes in. It consumes an iterable of iterables, unrolling each one in series. Like the other pieces, chain will produce a new generator, not a new list, so we again save on memory. If you indeed want a list, you can feed it to `list()` at the end. Or just make it the input to a `for in` construct.

Here's all of that broken out into individual operations with intention-revealing-variables:

```
elements = my_array[::2]
counts = my_array[1::2]
bypairs = zip(elements, counts)
repeated = (repeat(elem, count) for elem, count in bypairs)
flattened = chain.from_iterable(repeated)
list(flattened)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, skipping `itertools`, favoring generators:

```
def expanded(matrix):
    stream = iter(matrix)
    for element, count in zip(stream, stream):
        for _ in range(count):
            yield element

list(expanded(my_array))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
In [3]: my_array = ['name_1', 3, 'name_2', 2]
In [4]: out = [i for i, j in zip(my_array[::2], my_array[1::2]) for _ in range(j)]
In [5]: out
Out[5]: ['name_1', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_2']
```